# Best way to check failure on istream::read and istream::seekg

Tags: c++, io

suppose I have the following code:

```
std::ifstream file(name, flags);
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
// Check for error
file.read(buffer, size);
// Check for error
```

What is the cleanest way to check for an error seeking/reading? Should I just check the ios::fail and ios::bad bit? Will those failures trigger exceptions? (I believe you have to manually register the failure exceptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When these two functions fail they set certain flags in the error mask which you can check for in an if statement. The stream's boolean conversion operator will check the mask for `failbit` or `badbit` and will return true if neither of these are set. By default exceptions aren't thrown but you can set exceptions with the `exceptions()` method.

```
if (!file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg)) {
  // Check for error
}

if (!file.read(buffer, size)) {
  // Check for error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `::std::iostream::exceptions` method to make it trigger exceptions automatically when corresponding check fails:

```
file.exceptions(::std::ios_base::failbit | ::std::ios_base::badbit | ::std::ios_base::eofbit);
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg); // will throw std::ios_base::failure if fails
file.read(buffer, size); // will throw std::ios_base::failure if fails
```